# Persisting form data in Java Beans

Tags: java, javabeans

When I send a data through a form, I use reusable component JavaBean to store the data and retrieve it using get property and pass that data where ever I need it in the application.

But if I restart the web server, whatever data I had passed to that JavaBean will be lost and again I need pass the data to that Java Bean. Is there anyway to pass the data to the JavaBean and store (set) it permanently, so that i can access it even in the case of server restart?

Comment: To prevent a missunderstanding, what do you want to store? An object from your javabean or just the data?

Answer (score 0):

After you restart the server , the session of that client will be killed automatically, so you cannot hold the data in bean.

Answer (score 0):

Java beans stays in the memory and particularly within some scope (i.e. request, session, application , etc..)

Now if you restart the app server it is definitely going to kill all scope and so the result.

if you want to persist data then use DBMS

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to persist the data across server restarts ( to a database, or a file for example ), but I find this scenario a little strange. What if two users set the same java bean? Who takes precedence? Or is the beans contents on a per user basis?

Comment: Hi DaveHowes, The bean's contents is on a per user basis. Here i am going to collect the Database server Ip, username and Password through a form. I use form data for subsequent access of some webpages[webpages retrieve data from database]. So, i need those collected form data to be permanent in a javabean rather asking user to enter database server ip,username again and again!!!

Comment: In which case I think that you will need to persist the information to some external storage - a database or file - keyed by the user credentials. If you already have a login system in place then the user id entered in that would be a good candidate key. If you don't have a login system in place then it's hard to see how you can move forward without implementing one.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to save objects, then you have to look for non rational database systems. The database system 'Objectivity' is such a representantiv of that.